# LINQ to JSON in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, json, linq

Is there such a thing as a [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) file? That is, *.json?

Can JSON be used in C# code without any JavaScript stuff, sort of as a replacement for XML?

And is there any official [LINQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query) to JSON stuff around for C#?

I did find one website for my last question, but it took me to a page to download JSON.NET, and that page doesn't seem to mention anything about LINQ.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Yes, there is such a thing as a *.json file. The MIME type is `application/json` ([source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type#List_of_common_media_types)). JSON is a text-based format though, so you could hypothetically store JSON-formatted data in a text file with whatever extension you choose.
2. JSON can absolutely be used independently of JavaScript. In some cases, it's probably better suited to representing your data than XML. JSON.org has a great comparison page between [JSON and XML](http://www.json.org/xml.html).
3. [JSON.org](http://json.org/) lists several JSON libraries for C# (for example, JSON.NET which you have already discovered), and most (if not all) of the collections that these libraries use should support LINQ. JSON.NET definitely does offer support for it. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998772/linq-to-json) or [here](http://json.codeplex.com/).

Comment: I think you're an impostor - a bagel, not a donut!

Comment: @ClayShannon Do bagels have the same brilliant sheen of sparkling, delicious glaze?

Comment: Yes, when smeared with beaten egg yolks - every bagel worth his Lachs knows that.

Answer (score 2):

Everyone tends to stick with the [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) (from the System.Web.Extensions library) when working with JSON in .NET. The handy part about this is the ability to create a custom [JavaScriptConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptconverter.aspx) that will take custom objects and serialize them the way you chose. Likewise, you can make a deserialization method to receive in custom JSON formatting.

Though this of course depends on your application. Given that it's a [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_software) application, is there any particular reason you'd chose JSON over storing the information natively or just use the XML format? If your application communicates with webpages, the JavaScriptSerializer is probably the best bet, though if you're using it to store/retrieve settings I'd use XML. And, if it's necessary to synchronize your application with a web-based one, just serialize to JSON when the time is ready.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I just chose JSON for something new to learn, and I really dislike XML. I don't know why, there's just something about it I don't like, can't put my finger on it though. Atm, I am using XML to store configuration info, settings, and other user preferences.

Comment: @Lucifer: You're going to find a lot more flexibility with XML than you are with JSON. XML has more decorating attributes for its serializers and makes storing/retrieving information almost seamless. Also can handle up-revving your configuration files (adding new properties that may not exist in the last save). But, ultimately, to each his own.

Answer (score 1):

You can deserialize your JSON file into C# objects. After that, you can query with LINQ on these objects.