# How can I create a simple database without actually using a database software (like Access / local SQL)?

Tags: c#, database, file

I was thinking about creating a simple database where I can store some text, nothing more.
My question is: What is the best way to store data without using multiple files?

To my mind came CSV, but I am not sure if this is a proper solution...

Thanks for answers!

Comment: If you mean to store data, how about `json`, `xml`... Even `text`

Comment: How simple are we talking? You can make a program that saves information to a text file.

Comment: You would still have to implement a way to query your "database". Not sure why you don't want to use a "database software (like Access / local SQL)"? `MySQL` is free and fast.

Comment: It is also possible to query it inside the tool using Linq (once you got a list out of the data).
But the thing is, I would like to set it up as easy as possible, without using additional software. XML is quite a good solution, i think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use XML if you need to store just text . It also gives you more structure.

http://forums.devshed.com/xml-programming-19/xml-alternative-databases-34313.html

Comment: Thank you, that sounds nice!


Oh, and I forgot: It is also possible to serialize objects (creating a file out of an instance, and reverse)

Answer (score 1):

There's always xml. You can even use linq with that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: There is also [LINQ to JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/998772/linq-to-json)

Comment: Of course there is. There are also several linq-to-csv libraries. The reason I didn't mention them is that they are 3rd party libraries and not included in standard .NET. (I'm not saying they're bad, though. They can be just as good). I think JSON is also a good option.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a real sql database, you can use SQLCe. Its a SQL Database in a file.

#### More Information

- [SQL Server Compact connection strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-compact/)
- [Code First with SQL CE](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/680116/Code-First-with-SQL-CE)

Comment: I thought the OP said `without actually using a database software`.

Comment: I think he dont want to use a server software.

Comment: Make him aware of that in your answer. He didn't specify anything.

Comment: Yeah, thank you, but @afaolek is right. I really want to avoid using a real database, in order to have a very easy setup, also, without using additional software.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a JSON-like file text. Easy to Read, easy to Dump / Save and easy to modify as its supported in all major languages.

**Read more here:**

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with C#, you could easily use an excel worksheet. ( but as suggested json,xml, plain text will work too)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to suggest to use **XML** for database.
 **Why:**

- Easy to query.
- Easy to save data to.
- Easy to edit.
- Very light weight.

You can use LINQ-to-XML to "save-to and retrieve-from" data.